# Sitecore analytics not tracking logged-in users

Tags: xdb, wffm, experience-analytics

Our site is set up so certain content is protected to logged-in users only. We're using WFFM to do the login form with the login save action, and the user pool is in a custom domain instead of the standard "extranet" domain that ships with Sitecore. The client is reporting that they aren't seeing any data from logged in users, but it seems to continue tracking people as anonymous users.

Since we're using a custom domain, is there something extra that needs to be done for analytics to track those users? Is there another possible reason why analytics wouldn't switch from tracking a user as anonymous to tracking them as logged in?

Comment: Does these secured pages have separate layout? if so, check if it has Visitor Identification element

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just because you are logged in does not mean it will treat the user as a contact in xDB. You should check out [**how to identify contacts**](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/contacts/identifying_contacts).

The key being to call `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Identify(identifier)`, where `identfier` is the username or email.